# Website replicating in React Native, WebView vs code, notifications needed

Tags: react-native, webview

first time asking here as i am looking for some guidance before i start coding.

I have been developing websites mostly in PHP/MySQL/Jquery for years. As I was requested to port a website to an app, I selected React Native in order not to learn 2 different languages for IOS-Android.

I subscribed to some react native lessons, as I found it very clear and fun to follow, and it indeed is.

But here I am finding that to replicate the website is a truly difficult task for me. A temporary version exists at https://app.thallo.care/app.php?language=en (view on mobile if you like). There are many fixed positioned things and floating menus that i cannot easily program on react native.

I tried webview, it works wonderfully, but i am not positive i will be able to implement notifications the way i want to, or custom app styling with inject javascript i am unsure it will work.

The only app difference comparing to the desktop version, is that the user will receive notifications. The website will have a calendar where he will add events, and i need to send notifications to the user device on the event datetime that he has set.

Now the question... Should i use webview and manage notifications on a third party app like amazon SNS or anything else, will i get per-user notifications on events with webview? (I dont need to open a specific page on the app, but it would be nice). Or should i insist on react native coding and try to replicate as much as possible, to be able to have proper notifications? Reminder - the events won't be sent by the app. they are stored in MySQL and should be stored on some other service as well (that i dont know of yet). I don't know also if the webview can handle the website programmed login-logout with $_SESSION php parameters.

I would really appreciate some guidance.

Thanks in advance,